# Error in before loading the RadForm in Telerik Winforms .Net Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, telerik, visual-studio-2019

When am trying to open designer form in Telerik Winform .net Core 3.0 project am facing this this error. I tried with clear solution, Rebuild Solution but not working ( I am using VS 2019 )

[image]

To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:

the designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The Designer inspected the following classes in the file \r\n Rad From1 The Base class 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.Radform' could not be Loaded Ensure The assembly has been refernced and that all Projects have been built

Answer (score 0):

Telerik says the designer for .Net Core is not available yet. See [Components not visible in VS 2019](https://www.telerik.com/forums/components-not-visible-in-vs-2019#lxDtIDEtnk2HgYKYJj16aQ)